# How to close file opened by Debugger automatically after debugging?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

While debugging, whenever we step into a method, the file which defines that method will be opened and remains open after debug - this messed up my files in Visual Studio. I want to be able to close those opened-by-debugger files after the debug finished.

Let's say I'm opening 5 files already and start debugging. After the debug, I have 10+ files opened which means there are 5+ "new & strange" files opened by the debugger. I don't want them, and just want to close them quickly

How can I do this?

Comment: Can we know why you intend on closing all the opened files.

Comment: @ckv: Let's say I'm opening 5 files already and start debugging. After the debug, I have 10+ files opened which means there are 5+ "new & strange" files opened by the debugger. I don't want them, and just want to close them quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea after a while:
You can pin the tab (tab == file) using addon [Visual Studio 2010 Productivity Power Tools](http://go2.wordpress.com/?id=725X1342&site=namgivu.wordpress.com&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvisualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fd0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef&sref=http%3A%2F%2Fnamgivu.wordpress.com%2F2010%2F07%2F14%2Fthe-addons-for-visual-studio-that-profits-me-_%2F). Then after the debug just right click tabs area and call "Remove all but pinned".

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a option "Recycle Windows" in former versions of Visual studio, which only added one additional window for all debug windows. But apparently this has been removed.